# Getting KeyInput in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, event-handling, keyboard

Trying to catch keyinput in my Silverlight application gives me problems because of the focus of the controls. The page consists of multiple controls so every time a diffent control has focus and so my KeyDownEvent usually fails.
One possibility is to assing a KeyDown event to ALL my controls and then to the method that processes them. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could catch the KeyDown in the page that contains all controls by overriding OnKeyDown.

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
  // Distribute to listeners from here
}
```

This works since the controls on the page bubbles the event upwards so that if the control (like textbox/button etc) doesn't handle the keypress the parent control gets a chance.

Comment: This acually works Almund. To see if I am actually typing or using hotkeys I can check a Boolean with a secundary KeyDown Event for the controls. Thanks!